# Expected Arguments 1-3, but got 0

Tags: angular, ionic4

### Error Params get Current Position for ionic 4

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l03yT.png)

I tried searching for any discussion, and did not find the answer.
in the indicated ionic documentation

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    // resp.coords.latitude
    // resp.coords.longitude
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error getting location', error);
});
```

my code's like this

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(pos => {
   let latLng = new google.maps.latLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
   this.map.setCenter(latLng);
   this.map.setZoom(15);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

when i hover. i got message

```
(method) Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback: PositionCallback, errorCallback?: PositionErrorCallback, options?: PositionOptions): void
Expected 1-3 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
lib.dom.d.ts(5389, 24): An argument for 'successCallback' was not provided.
```

I imitated the tutorial on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ru57AkoWMJ4&t=199s

I get an error in line 43 of him

Answer (score 6):

Try to change your code like this:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
   let latLng = new google.maps.latLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
   this.map.setCenter(latLng);
   this.map.setZoom(15);
 }, err => { console.log(error)});
```

Instead of returning `Promise` the function is requiring a `successCallback` that will be executed when the request is successful (same as `then`). So instead of calling `then` you need to pass your function as a first argument as I've done in my code. Also instead of calling `catch`, you can provide the `errorCallback` as second argument.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I solved it like this:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({maximumAge: 5000, timeout: 5000, 
enableHighAccuracy: false})
      .then((resp) => {
           //alert(resp.coords.latitude);
           //alert(resp.coords.longitude);
       }).catch((error) => {
           console.log('Error getting location', error);
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, the problem was the Geolocation package I was using. So, I added this import to the component.ts I'm using:

```
import {Geolocation} from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
```

Because by default it didn't import this one, which is the one I wanted to use, and I think that's what you're trying to do.